# MVC : calling helper class from Controller instead of via Model - bad practice?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In my Controller I have a line like this:

```
  $this->set('uid', Project::returnProjectUid($queryString));
```

Is this bad practice? Should I ALWAYS pass it to the Model which then calls this helper class or this an acceptable practice?

Thanks.

Comment: This is hard to answer without any context. Are you using the term "helper" as in the MVC "view helper", or just generally as in "utility"? What's this line supposed to do, logically?

Comment: It's not a view helper, it's actually a top level class and I'm calling a helper function in that class. I just figure it's redundant to call the Model function and then call the class function from the Model. I'm guessing it's not best practice really, but it seems silly to chain 2 functions when not needed.

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, any data shouldbe allways treated by the Model, no matter how simple is the call or the logic of that data management.

MVC is a pattern that helps you to keep good maintainability of your software, no matter the complexity of it. When you break the pattern in a simple part of your code, you cannot expect all your code is in that pattern, so any needed change will result in code study to be sure that part is in MVC or had the pattern broked.

Hope my English is understandable.

Regards.